# How can I calculate infinite series $\frac{1}{n.2^n}$ for $n > 2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

a few days ago I was confronted with this series, and my attempts to solve it by raising exponential powers failed. I know I should try with exponentials but dont know how!

$$A=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n.2^n}$$
$$e^A =\prod_{n=3}^{\infty}e^\frac{1}{n.2^n}$$

any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you get when you integrate
$$1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$$ termwise over $[0,x]$ and plug in $x=1/2$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen oh thank you sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

$\begin{align}\left(\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{2^{- n}}{n}\right)=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{- n}}{n} + \sum_{n=1}^{2} - \frac{2^{- n}}{n}\right)\end{align}$

Or,

$\begin{align}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{2} - \frac{2^{- n}}{n}\right) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{- n}}{n}=\left(- \frac{5}{8}\right)+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{- n}}{n}\end{align}.$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{- n}}{n}$ is a known series as $\text{ln}(2)$.